# Want Bitmap from glide with gif thumbnail

Tags: bitmap, gif, android-glide

I have a issue as Glide support for gif I am using gif as thumnail and loading url to imageview.***Issue is I want the Bitmap from imageview in new SimpleTarget.***

here is my code.

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url)
.thumbnail(Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.preloader))
.fitCenter()
.crossFade()
.into(Want bitmap here is it possible);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(url)
            .asBitmap()
            .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.placeholder)))
            .error(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.placeholder)))
            .dontAnimate()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    // resource: the required Bitmap
                }
            });
```

Comment: Not working.But I found the answer that they use the same image when you call it send time,so i used glide again with asBitmap().